# Have any economics papers used unified cure models?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, labor-economics, unemployment

Does anyone know if there are unified cure models (aka split population models) in time-until-employment studies that combine the mixture cure approach with the promotion time approach as described in this paper in epidemiology: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1471082x0800900202